# React Native, Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run my app in physical device but getting that error. I tried to clean gradlew with `cd android` and `./gradlew clean`. I also tried to clean cache but it's giving that error. I just install the react navigation and stack navigation after that I'm getting that error I also tried to reinstall navigation packages but still getting same error. Can anyone help me please? error and package.json is below

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.1",
    "is_js": "^0.9.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.16",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.10.0"
  },
```

Comment: okk wait i will remove it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**According to the Docs**

[When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

You may try enabling `multiDex` to resolve this issue

In your android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    /** ... */
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

*Clean your build and any installed instances in your physical-device as a precaution*

Comment: for me this is not working

Comment: @ShafqatBari and Hend El-Sahli, Its not working for me. Can you help me how you solved it ? I am getting another error after that:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'

Comment: @MuhammadTalha Remove the app from your physical-device or emulator, and `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli not worked. Please help me to resolve the error...

Comment: @MuhammadTalha I'd suggest you create a new question with detailed description of the error message